# Removing eventListener from the document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a resizable div and when user clicks on the draggable line then i want to attach the `mousedown` eventlistener to that attach the two event one is `mousemove` and `mouseup`.
but the problem is `onMouseUpLeftResize` event run when i click drag window i don't want to run this. i just want to clear it from document. how can i do this in react.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const storedResizerLine = resizableline.current;

    const onMouseMoveLeftResize = (event) => {
      // console.log(event);
      const resizableAreaWidth = window.getComputedStyle(resizableArea.current).width;

      const dx = event.clientX - x + 40;
      resizableArea.current.style.width = `${dx}px`;
    };

    let removeMouseUpeventListener = () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseMoveLeftResize);
    };

    let onMouseUpLeftResize = (event) => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMoveLeftResize);
      const resizableAreaWidth = window.getComputedStyle(resizableArea.current).width;
      const imageWidth = window.innerWidth - parseInt(resizableAreaWidth);
      const percentageIncrement = ((parseInt(imageWidth) - parseInt(CANVAS_WIDTH)) * 100) / parseInt(CANVAS_WIDTH);
    };

    const onMouseDownLeftResize = (e) => {
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMoveLeftResize);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUpLeftResize);
    };

    storedResizerLine.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDownLeftResize);

    return () => {
      storedResizerLine.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDownLeftResize);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUpLeftResize);
    };
  }, [resizableline]);
```

i have tried to remove eventListener but nothing work and i don't have any idea it runs the infinite loop

Comment: In the cleanup function you return from the effect, you specify `storedResizerLine.addEventListener("mousedown", ...)`. Shouldn't this be `removeEventListener`?

Comment: not working still it runs when i drag the mouse

Comment: try to add a demo in a codesandbox or elaborate more what you are trying to achieve